# Passing a query to hibernate as a parameter to another query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Why isn't this legal? - Im new to java/hibernate.

```
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT round(count(*) * 0.25) as x from carecube.scheduledprocedure");                
            Query query1 = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT scheduledprocedure.id FROM carecube.scheduledprocedure ORDER BY scheduledprocedure.id LIMIT 1 OFFSET :q1");
            query1.setParameter("q1", query );
```

I want to execute one query that holds the number of rows multiplied by a quarter..

Then I want to execute another query, and pass that result back as a parameter on my second query object.

Is it possible to open multiple query objects for the same session as above? 
When I try to pass in a query object (which should hold the number of rows) as a parameter to query1, I receive the following error:

"Could not determine a type for class: org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl"

Could some hibernate guru shed some light?

Thank you immensely.

Comment: A query cannot be a query parameter, that makes no sense.  If you want to /execute/ the first query, and get the result, and use the result as the parameter to a second query, than do that.   But that's different than using the first /query/ as a parameter.   (This is not a hibernate-specific principle - you will not find any SQL-like or SQL API where a query can be a query parameter, with high probability.)

Comment: to use first query as parameter you can just write it as is in query1 as subquery

Comment: That sounds about right BadZen. Would I call executeUpdate on the first one and then use that as a parameter for the second query?